# How to Transform Crosstab Query

Tags: ms-access-2010

Using cross tab query in MS Access SQL, how to transform table like this

```
IND  LBL     TICKETS
1    AN      101
2    AN       1
1    QZ      102
1    AP      100
2    AP       2
```

To this:

```
LBL  IND1  IND2
AN   101     1
QZ   102     0
AP   100     2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you most of the way there -

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(TICKETS) SELECT LBL FROM MyTable GROUP BY LBL PIVOT IND
```

Change `MyTable` to the name of your table.